# Error:‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I am getting the following error:
prog.cpp: In member function ‘void Sequence::GetSequence()’:
prog.cpp:45: error: ‘itoa’ was not declared in this scope

I have include cstdlib header file but its not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct predicate :
public binary_function<T, T, bool>
{
    bool operator() (const T& l,const T &r) const
    {
          return l < r;
    }
};

class Sequence
{
    public:
    Sequence(vector<string> &v)
    { /* trimmed */ }

void GetSequence(void)
{
    string indices = "";
    char buf[16];

    for( map<int, string>::iterator
            i = m.begin(); i != m.end(); ++i )
    {
indices = indices
                  + string(itoa((i->first), buf, 10));
    }

    SortedSequence("", indices);
}

// --- trimmed ---
```

Comment: What if you add `#include <cstdlib>`?

Comment: @H2CO3: `itoa` is not (a standard) declaration in `cstdlib`.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: not a dupe; the other question is about C.

Comment: @larsmans: I think that's being a little pedantic. `atoi` is part of C++ thanks to inheriting C library functions. Clearly the expectation is that `itoa` would come from the same place. In fact `itoa` is not part of the C library. Of course, neither is it a non-C addition that C++ provides.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: that final remark is quite important, though. Besides, C++ provides different alternatives to `itoa` than C, so there is a practical difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no `itoa` in the standard, but in C++11 you can use the [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) functions.

Comment: Yes, but you can't specify the base with `std::to_string` like you can with `itoa`

Answer (score 7):

In C++11 you can use `std::to_string`. If this is not available to you, you can use a `std::stringstream`:

```
std::stringstream ss; int x = 23;
ss << x;
std::string str = ss.str();
```

If this is too verbose, there is [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html). There are some complaints about the performance of `lexical_cast` and `std::stringstream`, so watch out if this is important to you.

Another option is to use a [Boost.Karma](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma.html), a sublibrary of Spirit. It comes out ahead in most [benchmarks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/performance_measurements/numeric_performance/int_performance.html).

Usually, `itoa` is a bad idea. It is neither part of the C nor C++ standard. You can take some care to identify the platforms that support it and use it conditionally, but why should you, when there are better solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I've found that `itoa` was not available in [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/) GCC at least until 4.9.3 but **is** available in [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) GCC 5.3.0.

It guess it's absense was related to [broken vswprintf](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37522) issue which also caused missing [`std::stoi`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw) and [`std::to_string`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975341/to-string-is-not-a-member-of-std-says-so-g#comment63754740_12975602) in MinGW.