# How can I update code::blocks to use TDM-GCC?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I need to use `unique_ptr` in my C++ assignment.

I downloaded a new compiler, TDM-GCC-4.7.1, and installed it. Then I changed the directory of GNU GCC Compiler to the installation path in option: `Setting->Compiler...->Toolchain Executable`.

But it doesn't work. When I define a `unique_ptr`. A error would occur: `"unique pointer is not a command of 'std' "`

The reason of using smart pointer is to provide strong exception safety, which is also a requirement of this assignment. I just need to use this new feature of C++11... Plus, the OS I use is Window 7.

Thanks!

Comment: Assignment?  You're in school?  A school that uses modern programming tools and techniques?  This is unheard of!  Also, please show your code.

Comment: Can you also post the code where you're trying to use this?

Comment: Are you invoking g++ with the command line option `-std=c++11`?

Answer (score 5):

In CodeBlocks you can set C++11 mode either in project compiler settings or global compiler settings. Since you may be using it more often, here is how you change it globally:

Go to Settings -> Compiler -> (There should be list of options here, in Compiler flags) -> Select "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"

Here is how to change it for a single project:

Go to Project -> Build options -> (There should be list of options here, in Compiler flags) -> Select "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"

Answer (score 5):

1. Download the latest tdm-gcc http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net
2. Settings->Compiler, Selected Compiler [GNU GCC Compiler] Copy and Create a new configuration [GNU GCC Compiler 4.9.2]
3. Detail configuration
   [image: detail configuration image]
4. Set the new compiler configuration as default by click `Set as default`
5. Change Compiler settings to `having c++11`.

PS: code::blocks ver 13.12, tdm-gcc 4.9.2

Answer (score 2):

1. Remember to  `#include <memory>`
2. Add `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++11` compiler flags......whichever works

Answer (score 0):

That might be a late answer, but for anyone who's asking for that, changing the option "linker for dynamic libs" from gcc to g++ works for me