# "auto changes meaning in c++11"

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, operators

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iterator>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a("hello world");
    for(auto it = a.begin(); it != a.end() && !isspace(*it); it++ )
    {
        *it = toupper(*it);
    }
    cout<<a;
}
```

There are two errors I get. One is as mentioned, "auto changes meaning in c++11" and the other is "!= operator not defined." Never had this problem before.

I only used the auto operator because the book suggested.

I'm a beginner, and getting back to learning after about 2 months.
Having trouble catching up.

Comment: Compile with `-std=c++11`. Also, this is better done by `std::transform` or a ranged for loop.

Comment: The compiler has c++11 enabled.

Comment: Then get a newer version I suppose.

Comment: Is "auto changes meaning" really an error or just an informational warning?

Comment: Can you `Cut` and `Paste` the exact error message. Also the exact command line you are using to compile the file.

Comment: What compiler and version is it?  By what process are you compiling?  Because it sure doesn't sound like you have C++11 enabled, seeing as how this is the exact error message `g++` gives when you *don't* have C++11 enabled.

Comment: C:\CodeBlocks\second\main.cpp|8|warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]|

Comment: C:\CodeBlocks\second\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\CodeBlocks\second\main.cpp|8|warning: 'auto' changes meaning in C++11; please remove it [-Wc++0x-compat]|
C:\CodeBlocks\second\main.cpp|8|error: 'it' does not name a type|
C:\CodeBlocks\second\main.cpp|8|error: expected ';' before 'it'|
C:\CodeBlocks\second\main.cpp|8|error: 'it' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 3 errors, 1 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|

Comment: I use codeblocks. I'm really comfortable with it.

Comment: Add the warning information to the question instead of posting it in the comment.

Comment: Are you comfortable with adding options for codeblocks to pass to the compiler?  Because despite your claim, you in fact do not have C++11 enabled.

Comment: How do I enable it? If someone could guide me, please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17203469/440119

Comment: A Google search for that error message turns up only this question. Please copy-and-paste the exact error message into your question. (Code::Blocks is an IDE, which has to be configured to use some compiler; unless the message is from your IDE, it's the compiler that's relevant.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code runs ok when compiled with `-std=c++11`, You may check it [here](http://ideone.com/mf74AV).

You can add the option in `Setting->Compiler->Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=C++11]` in CodeBlocks.

Answer (score 3):

As chris mentioned, using Range-based for loop is much better. It's closer to spirit of C++11 
and it's easier to learn for beginners. Consider:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
       std::string s{"hello, world"}; // uniform initialization syntax is better
       for (auto& c : s)  // remember to use auto&
         if (!isspace(c)) c = toupper(c);
       cout << s << '\n'; // remember the last newline character  
       return 0;
    }
```

-- Saeed Amrollahi Boyouki