# A very simple enum class error in C++

Tags: c++, class, enums

That's my code :

```
enum class MyEnum
{
    EnumValue1,
    EnumValue2 = 10,
    EnumValue3
};
int main()
{
    MyEnum value1 = MyEnum::EnumValue1;
    return 0;
}
```

when i compile this code i get an error code

```
error: 'MyEnum' is not a class or namespace
```

what's wrong is with it ?

Comment: Are you compiling under C++11 or newer?

Comment: i am not sure , but i am using Code::Blocks IDE 16.01

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188554/my-enum-is-not-a-class-or-namespace

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Do you know how to change your compiler in code::blocks. if yes then change it to c++11 or higher. enum class is only available in c++11 and above. if not look here to [learn how to change the compiler option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808650/how-can-i-update-codeblocks-to-use-tdm-gcc)

Comment: @SeekAddo Thank You so much :), you solved my problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tell g++ to follow the C++11 standard.

To do this in Code::Blocks, go to **Project** -> *Build options* and in the **Compiler settings** -> *Compiler Flags* tab, check "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" (make sure to change the behavior of g++ for the entire project, not only for the active target).

Comment: what u mean with (make sure to change the behavior of g++ for the entire project, not only for the active target) ?, can u explain ?

Comment: When opening the project's *Build Options*, on the left hand side there is a tree where you can select *ProjectName*, *Debug* or *Release*. In order for your modification to be global (and thus to be independant of the build target), you should select **ProjectName** in the tree before changing anything.

Comment: thank you, I checked "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" in Project -> ....... and also checked it in Settings -> Compiler Settings ..... , i had to check it in both places to made it works .

Comment: Also consider installing mingw-w64  (for some reason, C::B still distributes the old defunct mingw)

Comment: @AdelBenhamida I'm glad it helped.