# Problems with std::stoi, not working on MinGW GCC 4.7.2

Tags: c++, mingw

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string test = "45";
    int myint = stoi(test);
    std::cout << myint << '\n';
}
```

I tried this code on my computer which is running MinGW GCC 4.7.2. It gives me this error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong, I got this from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol). Its the exact same code. And its a different error from the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw).

Comment: It is the same error. Looks different but same case. MinGW issue.

Comment: I had this. I personally had to go in and manually comment out a PP condition and then it worked fine for non-wstrings.

Comment: @chris can you explain what you've had to comment out?

Comment: @orian, I highly suggest the patch in the answer. It works better, and it's safer and easier.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems your MinGW needs a patch: [Enabling string conversion functions in MinGW](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string)

> This patch enables the following list of C++11 functions and templates
>   in the std namespace:
>
> stoi, stol, stoul, stoll, stof, stod, stold,
>   to_string, to_wstring

In above link, there is a `.zip` file, download it and

- Copy wchar.h and stdio.h from the include directory in the zip file
  to the following directory (overwrite): C:\mingw\include (replace
  C:\mingw\ with the appropriate directory)
- Copy os_defines.h to the following directory (overwrite):
  C:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits (replace
  C:\mingw\ with the appropriate directory) (replace 4.7.0 with the
  correct version number)

Comment: People should note that **direct replacement of the files is not guaranteed to be safe on versions later than MinGW GCC 4.7** - use the pastebin snippets, open the files, and comment/add to the existing files. Applied as such, this still works fine on MinGW GCC 4.8.1 afaik

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php), which works correctly out of the box.  This is a fork of MinGW that can produce both 32-bit and 64-bit builds.