# stoi() CodeBlocks not working

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I am using codeblocks and i can't make `stoi()` function work. I read other questions regarding this issue but I couldn't solve it. I checked C+11, I am using namespace std and I have the string header. I don't know how can I solve this problem.

> ```
> error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope
> ```

Comment: Please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and describe your exact difficulty.

Comment: If this is what I think it is, it was fixed in newer versions of MinGW. Try http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/

Comment: Oh, sorry. I thought i wrote the error. Edited now.

Comment: I installed the version you linked but it is still giving the same error @chris

Comment: Well, there's always this: http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked when i patch @chris

Comment: Perhaps this is a dupe then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2?rq=1

Comment: I think i missed that one. Should i delete this? @chris

Comment: It's always good to have questions that help people find other questions.

Answer (score 1):

found the answer on almost the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16132279/4837151):

*"It seems your MinGW needs a patch: [Enabling string conversion functions in MinGW](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string)"*

From this link you can download a .zip, than follow the instructions.

> This patch enables the following list of C++11 functions and
>   templates in the std namespace:
>
> ```
> stoi, stol, stoul, stoll, stof, stod, stold, to_string, to_wstring
> ```

Attention, maybe you will haver errors with later versions, after using the copy/paste:

As [Conduit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1732865/conduit) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2/16132279#comment40489980_16132279):

> "People should note that **direct replacement of the files is not guaranteed to be safe on versions later than MinGW GCC 4.7** - use the pastebin snippets, open the files, and comment/add to the existing files. Applied as such, this still works fine on MinGW GCC 4.8.1 afai"

Answer (score 0):

I would use `atoi` on the `str.data()` returned value, since it is supported in all compiler versions.

Comment: atoi gave me another error. Because my string is not null terminated it doesnt work.

Comment: How about `str.c_str()` ? This should be guaranteed to be null terminated.

Comment: `str.data()` is also guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Comment: I could make it work with data(), thanks. But i would like to make stoi() work too if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
#include <string>
```

That should work. For reference: [C++11 standard plus minor editorial changes.](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Or perhaps you are forgetting to prefix with `std::`?

A workaround is calling `.c_str()` and using the `<cstdlib>` or `<stdlib.h>` functions.

Comment: I am already using that. That is why i dont understand the problem. I did everything i see from other posts and still not working.

Comment: In that case, can you just search in the header file? If needed make an file including only `<string>` and search in the preprocessor output.

Comment: Sorry, im pretty new to these stuff so what exactly should i do? I found the string.h file but i didnt understand a thing. @Deduplicator

Comment: @user3526673: First, `<string>`and `<string.h>` are different header files with different content. You really want the one without extension. Probably in the same directory though. Then serch for the prototype of `stoi()`. Anyway, first check if you used the right namespace.

Comment: I am looking at include files in MinGW folder and all the files are header files with the little "h" icon on them. Its name was actually "string" but i said string.h because it was a header file. There are no other string in the header folder

Comment: By the way, for C++11, there's [N3485](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf), if you'd appreciate a later version.

Comment: @chris: What else all is in there?

Comment: @Deduplicator, No clue to be honest. 4 pages of stuff by the looks of it :p