# How can I use C++11 in GNU GCC compiler in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++11, g++, codeblocks

I'm trying to use the function `stoi()` in a program which is a C++11 function but I can't configure my compiler to use C++11. I added the (-std=c++11) compiler flag but it didn't work. I also tried the (-std=c++0x) and it also didn't work. I also tried these options after updating the compiler to GCC 4.8 that should support C++11 and didn't work. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2) your problem? Not sure what version that got fixed in.