# MinGW g++ cannot find std::stof

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I just (re)installed MinGW from scratch, with gcc 4.8.1 (the latest available), and the following program won't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    float f;
    std::string s = "5.235";
    f = std::stof(s);
    std::cout << f << '\n';
}
```

Here's the command I use:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
```

I get this error:

```
test.cpp:8:9: error: 'stof' is not a member of 'std'
     f = std::stof(s);
         ^
```

The file `bits\basic_string.h` which declares `std::stof` is included properly in the `string` header, and I checked `bits\basic_string.h` for std::stof's declaration, and it's there.

After a bit of Googling I did find some old patches for MinGW (4.6 - 4.7) but they seem irrelevant since I'm on gcc 4.8.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015#c25

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems with std::stoi, not working on MinGW GCC 4.7.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2) See [Conduit's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2/16132279#comment40489980_16132279) comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about exact problem, but check [mingw-w64](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) they have gcc 4.9.2 for now. It compiles your code just well. (But since the mingw-w64 project on sourceforge.net is moving to mingw-w64.org it's better to use [mingw-w64.org](http://mingw-w64.org))

Despite of it's name it provides compilers for both x86 and x64 targets.

<sup>Probably this should be a comment, not an answer.</sup>

Comment: Stephan T. Lavavej's 64-bit MinGW distro is also a [good alternative](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html).

Comment: @remyabel Cool! Never knew he has it on his page. The most interesting stuff is that his MinGW is also bundled with boost and some other popular libs.