# 'stoi' was not declared in this scope [C++]

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I've build this simple application in C++ using the GCC COMPILER

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
string hello = "90";
int dunno;

dunno = stoi(hello);
cout << dunno << endl;
return 0;
}
```

But the compiler tells me that 'stoi' wasn't declared in this scope although I included string.h

Here is a screen of my compiler settings: http://prntscr.com/69buec

Comment: Did you specify C++11 support (`-std=c++11`, or `-std=c++0x` for ancient compilers) when compiling?

Comment: Are you using MinGW? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16132176/10077

Comment: Here is a screen of my compiler settings: http://prntscr.com/69buec

Comment: @Useless nothing changes... same problem. Screen: http://prntscr.com/69bye5

Comment: works for me, http://ideone.com/GPSAJz, we can't replicate this problem so we can't fix it.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson i'm doing---> http://prntscr.com/69c09j

Comment: This code does compile in MSVS 2013 express.  It does fail at ideone: https://ideone.com/wpM8Vs using gcc4.9.2

Comment: @NathanOliver It doesn't compile because your using c++ 4.9.2 and I am using C++14

Comment: @IrrationalPerson: Just saw that.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @IrrationalPerson oh wow.. and.. how to use c++14?

Comment: @Useless: `std::stoi` is defined in `<string>`, not `<string.h>` or `<cstring>`. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol.

Comment: @Useless it doesn't work the same! http://prntscr.com/69c4yj

Comment: why are people that make these stl libraries so forgetful that they forget a whole bunch of important functions that basically make up the string library, aslo forgetting to patch the compilers. >:(

Comment: So, what should i do now? @IrrationalPerson

Comment: change to new compiler though I don't think code::block has C++14 yet.

Comment: OMG what is the best compiler for c++? @IrrationalPerson

Comment: I use the g++ compiler most frequently

Comment: Neither Code::Blocks nor Dev-C++ is a compiler. Both are IDEs. They normally use the MinGW g++ compiler on Windows, which does not have a working `std::stoi`. See my previous comment.

Comment: First of all devc++ is bugged and I'm not at beginning... And then VC++ has a .NET footprint (pragma once, stdafx ecc...) @IrrationalPerson

Comment: g++ 4.9.2 with `-std=c++11` *should* work. [See it live](http://goo.gl/FVoCv2), so maybe I missed something.

Comment: @WhozCraig i'm using it and it does not work