# stoi was not declared in this scope, despite using C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, codeblocks

I am using c++11 with MinGW compiler on code::blocks. When I type:

```
int x = stoi("4");
```

I get the error: `'stoi' was not declared in this scope`, however it should be, and I can't figure out why it isn't.

This has been driving me up the wall, and I would love it if someone could help. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Older versions of g++ lacked that function.

Comment: Did you `#include <string>` and say `using std::stoi`?

Comment: This might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2

Comment: @user2760626 I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @Alf do you know how I can update it?

Comment: @Yaxlat: My latest MinGW g++ is 4.9.1 from the [Nuwen distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html), and it has `stoi`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok thanks a lot. Do you know how I can update it on code::blocks?

Comment: @Yaxlat: You can just install it somewhere then configure code::blocks to use it. I know it's possible because I've done that in the past. However, note that with Nuwen you get static linking of runtime etc. by default, large executables, and you don't get support for various source encodings (only UTF-8). For more flexibility you may consider some older version from MinGW 64, or some other distribution, or, ask Ruben over in the C++ Lounge here on SO, if he's still there.