# std::stod is not a member of std

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I can't compile  the following code

```
auto test = 42.02;
double right = std::stod(stck.top());
```

I'm using Code::Blocks and activated the build option to follow c++11 standard. The compiler does not complain about the auto declaration and compiles, when I put the line below in comments.

I included the string header. I'm not using a namespace.

I have no idea why this does not compile. Please help me!
edits:
My compiler is Standard MinGW GCC 4.9

For simplicity reasons, I tried the following: compiled with -std=c++11

```
#include <string>

int main(){
     double pi = std::stod("3.14");
     return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

error: stod is not a member of std.

Comment: What is `stck`? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Maybe your compiler standard library isn't updated for C++11?

Comment: CodeBlocks is **not** a compiler. Are you using MinGW? IIRC, versions from a year or two ago had `stod`, `stoi`, `to_string` etc. not defined even if you enabled `-std=c++11`

Comment: I'll look it up.
stck is an instance of a stack but that's not relevant to this example.

Comment: I'm using Standard MinGW 32-bit Edition GCC 4.9 Series.

Comment: Please include a declaration of `stck` and the compiler error

Comment: The compiler error was already stated in the headline as well. I edited it and also posted a more simplified version of the problem.

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16132176/problems-with-stdstoi-not-working-on-mingw-gcc-4-7-2) has relevant information about lack of support for these functions in **MinGW** ports of earlier g++. But first, have you remembered to specify C++11 or later, e.g. via `-std=c++11`?

Comment: Please list all flags passed to the compiler to build that code.  Ideally manuallly run the compiler with those flags on that code to confirm those flags are indeed ones that repo the error.

Comment: I only use-std=c++11. Also, I can get other c++11 specific code (like auto) to compile.

Comment: This is the same old issue that the dead version of mingw does not support `stoi`, `stod` etc. The best fix is to install MinGW-w64 as the compiler, which does support those functions (and c++11 threads)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::stod` is only available if you are at least using `std=c++11` to compile. Therefore, when you compile, just add the flag `-std=c++11` and you will be able to use `stod`

Comment: It has been mentioned several times that I've been using that flag.

Comment: Looks like you should refer to the link that Cheers and hth posted. Your compiler may need a patch in order for you to use std.

Comment: Already did as mentioned in the comments. But thank you for pointing it out again, will help others :-)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've most likely misspelled [std::strtod()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof)

You'll also need to

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: seems not http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/

Comment: Oh, good point. In that case, probably the compiler's not in c++11 mode, in which case using the older standard function will still work :-)

Comment: **−1** "Seems like you've most likely misspelled std::strtod", no. Also, noting in passing that where you really need `strtod`, including `<stdlib.h>` is less troublesome than `<cstdlib>`. But this latter point is a bit subjective: some folks place a lot of weight on appearing to be C++-ish, and argue that `<cstdlib>` is the C++ way (it's silly, but they do).