# g++ 'stod' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I am trying to compile the following code using g++ (version 4.8.1) in cygwin, and it seems that it cannot use the function stod():

```
//test.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string a="1.23";
    cout<<stod(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting this eroor:

```
test.cpp:9:14: error: 'stod' was not declared in this scope
  cout<<stod(a);
```

I read another thread that has the same problem. There, people suggested to use c++11 to address it. So I tried both the following commands to compile it but still got the same error:

```
g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test
```

Does anyone know a solution to this problem?

And how do I know that c++11 is enabled? Do I need to modify my code in order to use it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @101010 `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11` do the exact same thing.

Comment: @hvd Sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: This is a good question.  I copied your code exactly in linux (ubuntu 16.04 and g++ 5.03) and it worked and gave no errors.

Comment: This issue is mingw specific. The answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/16132279/1362568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in GCC 4.8 on Coliru (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a68ad0ca64c1bff) and also in Clang on my machine.  It could be that somehow your Cygwin system doesn't support this function.  I suggest you work around it by simply using good old [`strtod()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtod) instead.  That's probably what `stod()` uses under the hood anyway.