# cygwin g++ std::stoi "error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std

Tags: c++11, g++, cygwin

I have:

-cygwin 1.7.25 on windows 7/32bit

-g++  --version --> g++ (GCC) 4.8.2

-libstdc++.a --> gcc-g++-4.8.2-1

Tried to make a c++ 
Hello World:

```
#include <string>

int main() 
{
   std::string s = "123";
   int i = std::stoi(s);
}
```

compiling gives:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:6:10: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
  int i = std::stoi(s);
```

I searched for hours but I  still could not find a solution. What's the issue here?

Comment: Weird. It's supposed to work... This seems to be some strange bug.

Answer (score 12):

That's a bug, possibly an incomplete port of some library code to cygwin (it's a cplusplus11 feature) - some stuff has to be changed after all. Make sure to report it.

The solution is easy of course: `#include <cstdlib> strtol(s.c_str(),0,10);`

[www.cplusplus.com/.../strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/)

A similar mingw bug is mentioned also [here](http://tehsausage.com/mingw-to-string)

[std::stoi doesn't exist in g++ 4.6.1 on MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw)

Comment: also have this issue with the latest stable version of Cygwin, but with to_string

Comment: cygwin v4.9.2 Windows 7/64 still no stoi, but strtol does the job

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem yesterday. "error: 'stoi' is not a member of 'std'."

First, I made sure c++11 was enabled. Then, I updated the g++ compiler to the newest version. After that, this error disappeared.

Comment: Tested and works with G++ 4.9 on Debian. Although the user needed a Windows solutions

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is not being taken seriously. On windows your best bet is to probably use visual studio, as it is always kept up to date . The bug here is that the macro defs are wrong to begin with. The problem starts from iomanip.h and iosbase . So they would have to changed all of there code. There are user made patches for this but I would not trust them at all, as they may contain even more bugs then the original copies. But it's up to you , I just stick with visual studio express edition.

Answer (score 0):

stoi works correct only on mingw64 for me.
If you use Codeblocks, don't forget to check if your projects compiler is set to mingw64.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am working with -std=c++98, not -std=c++11 but I solved it with the following:

```
int i = std::atoi(input.c_str());
```

atoi() is waiting for c type null-terminated string, c_str() makes it null-terminated char*. To use atoi I also() added the following library:

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

my system is:

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
```