# Converting char to int in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a character from a c string to an int but I keep running into an error.

Here's my code

```
while(std::getline(file, line)){
            if(std::isdigit(line[0]) && std::isspace(line[1]) && std::isdigit(line[2])){
                SequenceArray.push_back(line);
                if(std::stoi(line[2])== (SequenceArray.size() -1)){
                    std::cout<< "Success" << std::endl;
```

The error that I keep getting is as follows:

```
 a1.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
a1.cpp:30:25: error: call of overloaded ‘stoi(char&)’ is ambiguous
     if(std::stoi(line[2])== (SequenceArray.size() -1)){
                         ^
a1.cpp:30:25: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from a1.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2823:3: note: int std::stoi(const string&, std::size_t*, int) <near match>
   stoi(const string& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2823:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char’ to ‘const string& {aka const std::basic_string<char>&}’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2926:3: note: int std::stoi(const wstring&, std::size_t*, int) <near match>
   stoi(const wstring& __str, size_t* __idx = 0, int __base = 10)
   ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/basic_string.h:2926:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘char’ to ‘const wstring& {aka const std::basic_string<wchar_t>&}’
a1.cpp:35:6: warning: label ‘std’ defined but not used [-Wunused-label]
      std:exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

Comment: I can't be the only one to think that the compiler's translation of the code's `line[2]` into the message's  `line.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(2ul)` is insane.

Comment: @molbdnilo g++ 4.9 made big improvements in its error messages over g++ 4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `std::stoi` missing, try `#include <string>` (and enable C++11). However see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145488/cygwin-g-stdstoi-error-stoi-is-not-a-member-of-std) - the Windows ports of g++ have had a long-standing issue with support of `stoi` and `to_string`.

The second error is that `std:exit` should be `std::exit`.

The third error is because of `line[2].c_str()`.  You have not told us what `line` is but the error message suggests it is a `std::string`. So `line[2]` is a `char` and `char` does not have any member functions.  If you explain what you are trying to do in the code `std::atoi(line[2].c_str())` someone will be able to help. Maybe you meant `line[2] - '0'` which will give an integer between `0` and `9` if the third character in the line was a digit.

Comment: @Clockwork again `line[2]` is a `char` so you cannot call `stoi` on it. `char` and `string` are different. A char is not just a short string.   If `line[2] - '0'` is not what you want then please explain in words what you want that piece of code to do , as it is not clear.

Comment: How do I convert a char to an int in that case. It is the number being retrieved by getline( ) as a char

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70305/discussion-between-clockwork-and-matt-mcnabb).

Answer (score 3):

A **char** implicit converts to a **int**, you don't need to use extra functions.

'a' = 97, 'b' = 98, 'c'=99, etc., following the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) table

So if you write,

```
char a_char = 'a';
int a_val = a_char;
cout << a_val << endl;
```

you have:

```
97
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because you haven't enabled C++11 support. GCC currently chooses C++03 by default, and `stoi` didn't exist in that version.

Add `-std=c++11` to the compiler's arguments. If that doesn't work, try `-std=c++0x`, and think about getting a more up-to-date compiler. If you're stuck with an ancient compiler, then use `atoi` as in the code you originally posted (or perhaps something involving `strtol`, if you want to detect errors).

Also make sure you've included `<string>` for the declaration of that function.

The second error is because you wrote `:` instead of `::`.

Comment: @Clockwork: As I said, add `-std=c++11` to the compiler arguments. In your case, add it to the definition of `CXXFLAGS` in the makefile.

Answer (score 0):

std::stoi() is C++11. Not all compilers enable C++11 by default.