# ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, cygwin

So this error have been addressed several times, but no answers helped me. I'm using Notepad++ and Cygwin on windows 10. My code is as follows and it's from [Derek Banas's 1 hour C++ tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rub-JsjMhWY):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream> 
//#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string numberGuessed;
int intNumberGuessed = 0;
 do {
    cout << "Guess between 1 and 10: ";
     getline (cin,numberGuessed);
     intNumberGuessed = stoi(numberGuessed);
    cout << intNumberGuessed << endl;
 } while (intNumberGuessed != 4);
   cout << "You Win" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the error I get:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -static ctut.cpp
ctut.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ctut.cpp:15:43: error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
      intNumberGuessed = stoi(numberGuessed);
```

You see I already have applied all the suggestions in previous answered threads. Is there anything I'm missing? Do I have to start using Ming? Since Notepadd++ is the one I found with the most upvotes in another topic here. This is what I found and tried but didn't work:
[Function stoi not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084783/function-stoi-not-declared)

Comment: what if you replace `stoi` by `std::stoi` ?

Comment: @oLen There's already `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @oLen ``$ g++ -std=c++11 -static ctut.cpp
ctut.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ctut.cpp:15:25: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’
      intNumberGuessed = std::stoi(numberGuessed);``

Comment: So you're setting the `-std=c++11` option when compiling?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes `$ g++ -std=c++11 -static ctut.cpp` I have it tried with or without these options.

Comment: @Mohsen Which exact version of GCC are you using?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how can I find the answer to this question? I'm using the latest offered in Cygwin during the installation.

Comment: @Mohsen `g++ --version`

Comment: @GaryJackson thanks. 4.9.3 then.

Comment: @Mohsen I think it must be a Cygwin problem. I can't reproduce the error and I'm using 4.9.3 as well.

Comment: Try -std=c++0x. Maybe it works then.

Comment: @GaryJackson Notepad++ and Cygwin is the best way to run C++ in Windows isn't it? Or do you suggest another way? I might not use this function at all in my project but this error is bugging me so much I have stopped learning C++ the last 24 hours to find a solution! Or should I just leave it there? Any work arounds? Can you suggest another function to do this? I have already tried atoi but I get the very same error.

Comment: @Micha90 I tried and got the same error. ``$ g++ -std=c++0x -static ctut.cpp
ctut.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ctut.cpp:15:43: error: ‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope
      intNumberGuessed = stoi(numberGuessed);``

Comment: @Fireho yes `strtol` works the way it's mentioned there. Thanks for the link. I can't understand the variables 0 and 10 though but this `atoi` mentioned in the answer works just fine. I now figure out why I'm getting this error based on your link. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to comment yet :( but you could use `atoi(numberGuessed.c_str())` instead of `stoi()`.

Comment: Oh thank you so much it worked!

Comment: But _don't_.​​​ There are very good reasons that `atoi` was supplanted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit oh really? `strtol` then?

Comment: @Mohsen: Ideally you'd fix the problem at source and use `stoi`. But `strtol` is a viable workaround in the meantime, yes.

Comment: atoi has security issues right? Actually there are many ways to convert string to int. E.g. using stringstream or boost::lexical_cast etc.

Comment: @incBrain I'm gonna try them out, thanks.