# error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope (Code::Blocks 16.01 on Windows 10)

Tags: c++, c++11, windows-10, codeblocks

I get the error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope.

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
...
int x;
x = stoi(arg[0]);
```

I am running Code::Blocks 16.01 on Windows 10 with the -std=c++11 setting.

I didn't find any useful information on this page:
[‘stoi’ was not declared in this scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34580830/stoi-was-not-declared-in-this-scope)

I saw somewhere that upgrading gcc can fix this problem, but I didn't find an appropriate installation on the page: https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download

The same code works fine in Code::Blocks 13.12 on Linux Mint 17.3.

Is there a recommended fix for this problem?  Can this be fixed by using the 64 bit version of MinGW (assuming that is compatible with Code::Blocks 16.01)?

**Update**
there is a workaround, using atoi and c_str instead:

```
x = atoi(arg[0].c_str());
```

Comment: Did you turn on C++11?  Did you `#include<string>`?

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE. Windows is an OS. What is your *compiler* version?

Comment: The clue is in the question!  In other words whatever gcc ships with Code Blocks 16.01, I believe it is gcc 4.8, but don't quote me on that.

Comment: It is in your best interest to know what compiler version you are using. Find it out, don't outsource this to volunteer helpers.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this is a bug with MinGW. For more information, check out [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw). Specifically, DRH's answer.

Comment: If you believe the answer is on another question you should flag this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @NathanOliver I don't believe I have enough reputation to flag answers as a duplicate - otherwise I certainly would have.

Comment: Sure you can. [You can flag questions at 15 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)