# Coding in Command Line, what is -Wall?

Tags: linux, command-line, command-line-arguments

I'm in a coding class in which we are coding in C++ through Command Line arguments, but she is using certain things that I'm not able to find through googling but that I've seen elsewhere in posts on this site. My VM is a linux.

What does -Wall do in the context "g++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test"? My instructor also used -o and said it creates an executable file, but I don't see one being made. Is test a command? In layman terms would be best, if possible.

(Somebody used -Wall in a comment on this post for reference [Function stoi not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084783/function-stoi-not-declared))

In this vein, what other commands might be helpful when coding in command line? I'm familiar with very basic ones such as cd, ls, pwd, ./a.out, mkdir, cat, and vim (though in vim, I only know how to insert and exit/save).

Thanks for any help; -Wall is my main question but any help on the rest would be super appreciated.

Comment: Why not Google the manual page? Would have been quicker. Google man g++

Comment: Or use the man page, period.

Comment: Type `man gcc` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the downvotes! I literally didn't know the man page was a thing, and googling -Wall yielded no results, but they were probably justified. Sounds right. Legitimate thanks to Basile Starynkevitch!

Comment: It's harsh to down-vote this :/ Also, it's difficult to Google a term that matches a common word like "wall". It only takes ten seconds to answer the question, if you know the answer.

Comment: @ULTIMATEDEMISE2: If my answer fits, please accept it and/or upvote it.

Comment: I don't have the rep to or I would.

Comment: @ULTIMATEDEMISE2 The tricky thing about googling compiler flags that start with dashes is that in google search, starting a term with a dash means to **exclude** things that match that term from the results. So to actually get the dash, you need to wrap it with quotes like `"-Wall"`.

Answer (score 4):

From the `g++` man page:

> ```
>   -Wall
>       This enables all the warnings [...]
> ```

There's more, feel free to read it.

Answer (score 2):

Bless your instructor to teach you compiling on the command line!

The [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler has an extensive documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc) (and might be installed on your computer, available thru `info gcc`). Read notably the [GCC command options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.htm) chapter (about invoking GCC). You might also try the man pages with `man gcc` command (but try before `man man` to understand [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html)...). For `gcc`, the man page is incomplete (w.r.t. `info gcc`). And you could also try `gcc --help`.

I strongly recommend compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (for C code) or `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`  for C++ code (also add other useful options such as `-std=c++11`). The `-Wall` option asks for almost all warnings, the `-Wextra` ask for some more of them, and the `-g` option is asking for debug information (in [DWARF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) format these days). You then can (and should) use the [GDB debugger](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/). Read the [Debugging with GDB](https://sourceware.org/gdb/download/onlinedocs/gdb/index.html) manual.

Later, your excellent instructor probably will teach you about using [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tools (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/)) which nicely runs commands (notably compilation commands) to automate the build process. A complex program made of several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) and even using ad hoc C code generators (e.g. [bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/)) can be compiled using `make` or `ninja`

Also, you'll probably learn about [version control systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control_system) such as [git](http://git-scm.com/).

BTW, I do recommend downloading and studying the source code and building some of the many [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) programs (e.g. on http://github.com/ or elsewhere). You'll learn a lot.

BTW, avoid naming your [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) `test` since `test` is a very *standard* command (see [test(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/test.1.html)) often implemented as a [shell builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html).