# Error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’

Tags: c++, netbeans, compiler-construction, gnu

I'm using NetBeans 7.4 and I want to use `std::stoi` in C++ but this error keeps popping out. I just installed the newest g++ (with cygwin) but it didn't change anything. I also added `-std=c++11` then `-std=c++0x` to command line and nothing changed. Any help?

Comment: Did you incluide `<string>`?

Comment: Yes I did. Full include: #include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

Comment: "this error", which is .. ?

Comment: Better show your code here.

Comment: Which is the name of the topic. main.cpp:16:15: error: ‘stoi’ is not a member of ‘std’

Comment: @user3369008, sorry , my bad. :)
can you show some code pleaase

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo it's not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @user3369008 See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw it's for MinGW, but it probably applies to CygWin too.

Comment: Uh... I'll try that or resort to Linux, heh. THanks

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue with gcc version 4.7.2 but did reproduce it with gcc 4.1.