# GCC 4.8.1 std::to_string error

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, mingw

I have been able to find quite a few questions on this, but all seem to point that it should be working with gcc 4.8.1 if you compile with -std=c++11

Here is my output of g++ --version:

```
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Yet when I try to compile something with std::tostring even with a simple command like this:

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++11 -o "Main.o" "Main.cpp"
```

I get the following error:

```
Main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Main.cpp:6:26: error: 'to_string' is not a member of 'std'
  std::string intString = std::to_string(1335);
```

Even on a file as simple as:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::string intString = std::to_string(1335);
    printf(intString.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas? This is on Windows 7 64-bit using the latest version of MinGW.

Comment: Pls provide the code where it shows the error.

Comment: You should at least show us the definition of `testFunction`

Comment: Did you include the header like #include <string> ?  Did you use "std::" or "using namespace std"?

Comment: I get this error even on something as simple as:

int main()
{
 printf(std::to_string(1335));
 return 0;
}

Comment: @Nabren, unless you include the header where it is declared/defined, this isn't allowed in C++.

Comment: I updated the code to be a more simple file that still produces the error. I know you have to include the header that defines it...

Comment: Printf doesn't take a std::string argument.

Comment: @stefan, std::string is convertable into a const char*, though. Regardless, that's not even the issue... just a bad example on my part. I'll update the code again so that isn't made to be the blame.

Comment: @Nabren: yes, but the conversion isn't implicit. You have to call .c_str() if something is irrelevant to your question, don't even include it..

Comment: you'r useing cygwin?MinGW?

Comment: MinGW, but all indications seem to be pointing to the latest version of MinGW has this working.

Comment: @Nabren Here's the [bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52015) tracking this issue. From reading that, it's fixed if you use mingw-w64, still broken for the 32-bit version.

Comment: Further discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw

Comment: @Praetorian, looks like that was it. I was skimming over some of those bugs reports and kept seeing indication it was fixed in 4.8 - I guess I didn't read down far enough :(

Comment: @stefan Are you the real STL? :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Afraid not, my name is SDL though ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MinGW is a port of GCC over to windows. Your issue is a MinGW issue (as some comments have already noticed)
If you're going to be doing REAL C++ development on windows, I suggest you use MSVC. No, really, despite microsoft being evil.
Anyway, here is Coliru showing it works fine on legitimate gcc: [away!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/761a41b55b3d4713).
And [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25c942d99041a250) is how I would do it (if you're using c++11, might as well use actual STL?)

(Note: If you want it cross platform, you can use clang or proper build tools)