# error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope in Code::Blocks 16.01

Tags: c++, c++11, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks 16.01 and running the following code produces an **error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long int i = 10000000;
    cout << to_string(i);
    return 0;
}
```

Note: Already ticked "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard" in compiler flags.

Comment: Which os and compiler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12975602/1981581

Comment: If you did indeed [set Code Blocks to use C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18174988/how-can-i-add-c11-support-to-codeblocks-compiler) then your code should work fine as written.

Comment: Windows 10 and GNU GCC Compiler which was included in codeblocks.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate, as pointed out in the comment by @odyss-jii .
I could confirm the error on my old installation of CodeBlocks on Windows. According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31767452/4770166), installing a more recent compiler version should help.