# Why is stod "not declared in this scope"?

Tags: c++

I am trying to use `stod()` but I am getting the error: 'stod' was not declared in this scope.

I HAVE enabled c++ 11 and c++ 0x standards and neither have worked. As far as I can see, that is the only solution any of the other questions like his have come to.

using CodeBlocks 16.01

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
double questions[5][5];
string inLine;
string buffer[5][5];
int found;
ifstream inGrade ("Grades.txt");

if (inGrade) {
    while (!inGrade.eof()){
        getline(inGrade, inLine);

        while (inLine != "\0") {
            found = inLine.find(" ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                for (int j= 0; j < found; j++) {
                    buffer[i][j] += inLine[j];
                    questions[i][j] = stod(buffer[i][j]);
                }
            }

            inLine.erase(0, found + 1);
        }
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: std::stod(buffer[i][j])

Comment: on build it says error: 'stod' is not a member of 'std'

Comment: Try compiling it using g++ or cpp.sh (Online c++ Compiler)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: What's your compiler (and its version)?

Comment: I believe I am, the compiler setting I have selected is "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard [-std=c++11]"

Comment: I can suggest you to use Visual Studio instead of CodeBlocks, but it's just an advise :)

Comment: GNU GCC Compiler?

Comment: Tag people when you answer them (with @ character), or they won't be notified. What version is your GCC? Can you run `g++ --version` from the command line?

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, how would I check that?

Comment: I'm afraid an SO comments are not the platform for such troubleshooting. Try uninstalling & reinstalling code::blocks (along with the compiler provided) to the latest stable version.

Comment: This is a bug related to MinGW-32, [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221). You have to use MinGW-64