# std::stoi() not declared in this scope, g++ (GCC) 5.3.0

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, mingw, std

I'm still having an issue with the bug from [g++ 4.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542221/stdstoi-doesnt-exist-in-g-4-6-1-on-mingw) however the solution provided doesn't seem relevant to g++ 5.3.0. Is there any other workaround besides installing mingw-w64?

My build command is:

```
g++ main1.cpp main2.cpp -g -std=gnu++11 -o program.exe
```

Comment: My current solution is to use atoi(str.c_str()) in place of stoi().

Comment: The best place to ask about this is on the MinGW mailing list. They've been more than accomodating fixing bugs for me before, they'll probably fix this too. See here : https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/mingw-users